# 'npm' isn't recognized in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm using Docker with a WSL2 backend:
[image: docker general settings]

From what I understand, the base image `node:lts-bullseye` has npm installed. I've also replicated my project partners steps on another machine and got the same error (My project partner and I have been trying to figure this out for weeks).

Here is my console after running `docker compose up --build`:
Notice how the first error says `unknown command: "install` which implies the image doesn't recognize npm. The second error `missing script: dev` implies my package.json either doesn't have the dev script or is in the wrong directory which isn't the case for either option.

FYI: I ran a different project through docker and it worked just fine, it just didn't use a shell script so I don't think it's a docker issue.

```
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait]  docker-compose-wait 2.9.0
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] ---------------------------
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait] Starting with configuration:
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - Hosts to be waiting for: [mongo:27017]
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - Paths to be waiting for: []
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - Timeout before failure: 60 seconds
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - TCP connection timeout before retry: 5 seconds
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time before checking for hosts/paths availability: 5 seconds
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time once all hosts/paths are available: 0 seconds
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time between retries: 1 seconds
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [DEBUG wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] Waiting 5 seconds before checking for hosts/paths availability
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-ghi-1            | Installing dependencies...
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.882+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.884+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.884+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.885+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"bb5817e3662c"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.9","gitVersion":"90c65f9cc8fc4e6664a5848230abaa9b3f3b02f7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2204","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"22.04"}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.889+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.889+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:24.890+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3442M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [INFO  wait]  docker-compose-wait 2.9.0
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [INFO  wait] ---------------------------
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait] Starting with configuration:
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - Hosts to be waiting for: []
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - Paths to be waiting for: []
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - Timeout before failure: 30 seconds
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - TCP connection timeout before retry: 5 seconds
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time before checking for hosts/paths availability: 0 seconds
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time once all hosts/paths are available: 0 seconds
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time between retries: 1 seconds
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [DEBUG wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-fastapi-1        | [INFO  wait] docker-compose-wait - Everything's fine, the application can now start!easyfood-fastapi-1        | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
"asyfood-ghi-1            | Unknown command: "install
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | Did you mean one of these?
easyfood-ghi-1            |     npm install # Install a package
easyfood-ghi-1            |     npm uninstall # Remove a package
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
easyfood-ghi-1            |   npm help
easyfood-fastapi-1        | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
easyfood-fastapi-1        | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
easyfood-fastapi-1        | INFO:     Started reloader process [8] using watchgod
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm
easyfood-ghi-1            |  ERR!
"asyfood-ghi-1            |  Missing script: "dev
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm ERR!
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm ERR!
easyfood-ghi-1            |  Did you mean this?
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm ERR!     npm run dev # run the "dev" package script
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm
easyfood-ghi-1            |  ERR!
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm ERR!   npm run
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | 
easyfood-ghi-1            | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-07T03_16_25_415Z-debug-0.log
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.023+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1133}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.023+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.047+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22178,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.047+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5123300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"vm.max_map_count is too low","attr":{"currentValue":65530,"recommendedMinimum":1677720,"maxConns":838860},"tags":["startupWarnings"]}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.052+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.052+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"startup"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.052+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.055+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.056+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.065+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.065+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.068+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.068+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.068+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.260+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.4:44568","uuid":"8fe48720-ee58-43b3-a375-fc6920a70b1d","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.260+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.4:44568","client":"conn1","doc":{"driver":{"name":"PyMongo","version":"4.2.0"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"x86_64","version":"5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2"},"platform":"CPython 3.10.13.final.0"}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.263+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.4:44570","uuid":"5606afcf-7b73-425b-8b70-e9c515923f95","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:26.263+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.4:44570","client":"conn2","doc":{"driver":{"name":"PyMongo","version":"4.2.0"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"x86_64","version":"5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2"},"platform":"CPython 3.10.13.final.0"}}}
easyfood-fastapi-1        | INFO:     Started server process [10]
easyfood-fastapi-1        | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
easyfood-fastapi-1        | INFO:     Application startup complete.
easyfood-ghi-1 exited with code 1
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] Checking availability of host [mongo:27017]
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:29.407+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.2:60860","uuid":"3b1cff67-8f23-4e3a-8993-a2af9387e8b4","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":3}}
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] Host [mongo:27017] is now available!
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] docker-compose-wait - Everything's fine, the application can now start!easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:29.408+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.2:60860","uuid":"3b1cff67-8f23-4e3a-8993-a2af9387e8b4","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":2}}
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | [INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | Welcome to mongo-express
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | ------------------------
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | 
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | 
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | 
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:29.906+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.2:60872","uuid":"85da578b-15fa-4a68-8e7e-5409edb3ef93","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":3}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:29.914+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.2:60872","client":"conn4","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2"},"platform":"'Node.js v12.22.7, LE (legacy)"}}}
easyfood-mongo-1          | {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-07T03:16:29.932+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"Authentication succeeded","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"example_user","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"172.20.0.2:60872","extraInfo":{}}}
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
easyfood-mongo-express-1  | basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!
```

Here is my **file structure**:

[image: file structure]

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "vehicle-data",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Here is my **docker-compose**:

```
volumes:
  easy-food-db:
    external: true
services:
  fastapi:
    environment:
      CORS_HOST: http://localhost:3000
      VITE_SIGNING_KEY: ${VITE_SIGNING_KEY}
      VITE_API_KEY: ${VITE_API_KEY}
      DATABASE_URL: mongodb://example_user:example_password@mongo
    build:
      context: api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
  ghi:
    image: node:lts-bullseye
    command: /bin/bash run.sh
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./ghi:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      HOST_OS: ${OS}
      NODE_ENV: development
      HOST: "0.0.0.0"
      PUBLIC_URL: http://localhost:3000
      REACT_APP_API_HOST: ${REACT_APP_API_HOST}
  mongo:
    image: mongo:6
    volumes:
      - easy-food-db:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: example_user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example_password
  mongo-express:
    build:
      context: db/mongo-express
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: example_user
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example_password
      WAIT_HOSTS: mongo:27017
      WAIT_BEFORE: 5
      WAIT_TIMEOUT: 60
```

Here is my **run.sh**:

```
echo "Installing dependencies..."
npm install
npm run dev
```

**ANYBODY ELSE HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM OR ANY SOLUTION IDEAS?**

Comment: Please share your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @RobinThomas there isn't one. OP is using the image in Docker Compose directly

Comment: @Phil True. There is a `Dockerfile.dev` mentioned in the compose yml (which I mistakenly thought was being used in other services as well).

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77004827/283366)? You haven't added anything new in this one. Did you try the suggestion I left last time?

Comment: @Phil Yes I did. Unfortunately no luck. I was met with the same ```unknown command: "install``` and ```missing script: "dev``` errors.

Comment: Did you make sure all the required files were present in the right directories? Are you able to bypass `run.sh` and run `npm install` directly?

Comment: @Phil yes. When I list the directories after running ```docker compose run ghi bash``` everything within the "ghi" folder shows. I actually just ran it again and noticed the ".eslintrc.cjs" file doesn't appear even though it does in my code editor.

Comment: Notice that the error line _begins_ with a `"` as its first character, and there's mismatched `"install` without an ending quote at the end.  This looks like it's very likely a DOS line-ending issue, what you might get if you ran `npm install\r` ending with a carriage return.  You could potentially fix this in a Dockerfile but a `volumes:` that injects code into a container will hide that fix.

Comment: @Phil I followed your suggestion [in my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004827/docker-container-not-recognizing-npm) by running `docker compose run ghi bash` followed by `/bin/bash run.sh` and was given the same error as above. I then ran `/bin/bash npm install` and was met with the follow error: `usr/local/bin/npm: npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'../lib/cli.js''
/usr/local/bin/npm: npm: line 2: `require('../lib/cli.js')(process)'

Comment: You don't prefix `npm install` with `/bin/bash`